# Oracle 19c Installer hangs with endless Reading from the pipe output

Tags: oracle, installation, hang

I am attemping to install Oracle 19c on Windows 10 64 bit.
No Oracle products have ever been installed on this machine.
When I run setup.exe the cmd window launches, then the splash screen and then the installer window
comes up but never populated. It just has the processing cursor. Doesnt matter how long I wait, nothing happens.

The OracleRemExecServiceV2 is installed and running. It was left behind by killing the install.
I removed it, rebooted and tried the install again with the same results.

So far I have done the following:

1. Removed the OracleRemExecServiceV2 service.
2. Full registy search (not whole word) for oracle returned the usual suspects:
   Microsoft .Net, ODBC, OLE DB, SQL Server and Visual Studio clients.
3. Using bash in /mnt/c, find . -iname "*oracle*" which found the setup directory, the InstallActions directory and the aforementioned client assemblies.

So, to the logs. Early, there is a warning which seems to be corrected.

```
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Opening bean stores from which the beans can be loaded
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Loading beanstore from a given input stream
    WARNING:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Unable to create xml tag for the key:CommonProgramFiles(x86)
    WARNING:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Unable to create xml tag for the key:ProgramFiles(x86)
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Translating external format into raw format 
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Loaded BeanStore using the flow data defaults
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] No global condition definition found.
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Building the flow graph
```

At the end of the log, when all preparation is complete (all background tasks are complete) the installer starts.

```
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Waiting for completion of background operations
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Completed background operations
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Validating view at state <supportedOSCheck>
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Completed validating view at state <supportedOSCheck>
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Validating state <supportedOSCheck>
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Verifying target environment...
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:15:00] Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:23:38] Pause Oracle Database 19c Installer
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:23:42] Resume Oracle Database 19c Installer
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:04] Pause Oracle Database 19c Installer
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Resume Oracle Database 19c Installer
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Adding ExitStatus USER_CANCELLED_INSTALL to the exit status set
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] The inventory does not exist, but the location of the inventory is known: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Exit Status is -4
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Shutdown Oracle Database 19c Installer
    INFO:  [27-Dec-2021 22:26:06] Unloading Setup Driver
```

You can see the gap from 22:15 to 22:23 until I killed it.

Looking at the InstallActions folder, I found a InstallActions.out file that is 1.7GB. Inspecting that file reveals that all appears well, missing values are created, etc.
Starting at line 380 we have

```
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:40:57.120 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Trying to open a named pipe
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:40:57.120 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  About to open pipe
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:40:57.120 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  calling create file for pipe \\GOANNA\pipe\srvmremotexecpipev2
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Local pipe failed (53), retry using local pipe notation
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  calling create file for pipe \\.\pipe\srvmremotexecpipev2
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Created handle to Pipe 
    
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Pipe has connected, set the handle state
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Fill up the request message
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Finish filling up the request message
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.133 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Sending a message to the pipe server. Total bytes to write=18528
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.134 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  After call to WriteFile. totalWritten=18528, cbWritten=18528
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:41:57.134 GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Reading from the pipe
```

followed by about 17 million identical rows,

```
    [Worker 0] [ 2021-12-28 08:mm:ss.nnn GMT ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Reading from the pipe
```

I have no idea where to go next. InstallActions.err is empty.

This is my first question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I remember a similar problem, but I don't think it was on Windows, where the cause was the numlock key.  T h i s  i s  n o t  a  j o k e.

Comment: Regarding "Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined", do you have the host name and its IP address in the hosts file?  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc is where it's hidden.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille Neither of those had any effect. I also tried with Defender and vpn turned off. No luck.

Comment: Does any body suspect a pre-install a version of Java might help?

Comment: Java is of no use, the installer contains its own version.  None of your directories contains spaces or special characters?  Eg. "Oracle 19".

Comment: I just installed 21c with no issues. That;s a workaround. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing "Reading from the pipe"  messages in ...\Inventory\logs  OUT files then, login Windows with an admin account and run the services called "Server" and "Workstation".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.  I was logged in as admin and restarted the Server and Workstation services.  It did not help.

What ultimately worked for me was I disabled ALL my network adapters, and reran the install. The change was near immediate, and there were no further issues.

I do not know why it worked, I just saw someone else post a similar solution on another site and tried it.